# Как заполнить столбец DataFrame по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать функцию в столбце чтобы в нем в зависимости от условия требуемые данные записывались в строках. Например, есть такой фрейм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В строки столбца d нужно вписать такую функцию, которая возвращает нужный тип. Я себе это функцию так представляю:

```
def FindType(df):
    if c >= a:
        d = 'Type a'
    else:
        d = 'Type b'
```

Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте воспользоваться векторизированной функцией [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['d'] = np.where(df.c > df.b, 'Type a', 'Type b')
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос и успешно применил. В этой теме приведены примеры и описание https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe

В общем и целом для решения необходимо использовать метод apply с атрибутом axis=1.

Comment: сейчас случайно нашел этот вопрос... Использовать `df.apply(..., axis=1)` рекомендуют в самых крайних случаях, когда __ничего__ кроме этого не помогает. `df.apply(..., axis=1)` - это обертка вокруг обычного (не векторизированного) цикла.